# Extract from an email: Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to grab a specific email from Outlook with current date and specified subject. After this I want to copy the contents of the email (a table) to the active Excel sheet.

I'm looping through a generic object.

```vb
Sub Mail3()

Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String
Dim oMail As Object
Dim y As Long, x As Long
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim tb As Word.Table
Dim Myemail As String
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim irow As Integer
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ns As Namespace
irow = 1
'set email date
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")

Myemail = "abcd"
'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name to set the name of the inbox - I have several mailboxes, needed to specify
MailBoxName = "myinbox"

'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

'To direct to a Folder at a high level
Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

'copying the email contents into the refresh file
For Each oMail In Folder.Items
    If oMail.Class = 43 Then
        Set oMail = oItem
        If oMail.Subject = Myemail And (Now() - oMail.ReceivedTime) < 1 Then
            'oMail.SentOn = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) Then
            Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = oItem.HTMLBody
        End If
    End If
Next oMail

End Sub
```

---

I've changed a bunch of things.
This time using oMail as Object

Still getting error

> object not defined

here

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = oItem.HTMLBody
```

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . What did you try, what did you expect, etc.

Comment: You have `Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem` so if any item in the folder is not a `MailItem` you can't assign it to `oMail`.   `Dim oMail As Object` would be safer here.

Comment: If that's not the problem then please be more specific about the exact problem you're having.

Comment: @TimWilliams So I changed "If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then " to
  " If oMail.Class = 43 Then "
And it seems to have addressed the issue youre hinting at.

Im not sure though.

Now i get another error on the line right after that one. 

 If oMail.Subject = Myemail And oMail.SentOn = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)) Then

Run time error 91
Obejct variable or With block variable not set

Just to explain this line, 

I want only an email with a specific subject AND one thats recieved today to be picked up. I recieve one every day in my mailbox.

Comment: `oItem.HTMLBody` - you're working with `oMail` not `oItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence sets `oMail` to nothing.

```vb
For Each oMail In Folder.Items
    If oMail.Class = 43 Then
        Set oMail = oItem
```

You may declare variables this way.

```vb
Dim oItem As Object
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
```

Test in whatever way you wish that `oItem` is a mailitem.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Mail3_DifferentVariableNames()

Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim MailBoxName As String
Dim High_Level_Folder_Name  As String

Dim oItem As Object
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim mySubject As String

mySubject = "abcd"

MailBoxName = "myEmailAddress"

'Folder immediately under MailBoxName
High_Level_Folder_Name = "Inbox" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

Set oFolder = Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(High_Level_Folder_Name)

'copying the email contents into the refresh file
For Each oItem In oFolder.Items

    If oItem.Class = 43 Then
    
        Set oMail = oItem
        
        ' If noticeably slow there are methods to reduce the number of items processed.
        If oMail.Subject = mySubject And (Now() - oMail.ReceivedTime) < 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = oMail.HTMLBody
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> Still getting an object not defined error here

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = oItem.HTMLBody
```

You need to use the `oMail` object instead:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value = oMail.HTMLBody
```

Also iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. Instead,  use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class where you can deal only with items that correspond to the search criteria defined. Read more about them in the following articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Finally, you may also find the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) article helpful.

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thank you very much for your input.
The articles youve linked are super helpful, since Ive got the main functionality already Ill implement the Restrict or Find method.

Cheers